# Android clickable list item in a search interface

Tags: android

In my android app my search function works, the list gets correctly populated, but the items are not clickable. I'm trying to get that to work. Here's my code, can anyone see why the items are not clickable?

```
    private void showResults(String query) {
    Cursor cursor = DBHelper.searchDB(query);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] searchFrom = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_YEAR, DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_MODEL };
    int[] displayHere = new int[] { R.id.rTitleTV, R.id.rYearTV,
            R.id.rMakeTV, R.id.rModelTV };
    SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.record_2, cursor, searchFrom, displayHere);
    setListAdapter(records);
    DBHelper.close();

    // --- Click on list item ---

    ListView clickList = getListView();
    clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    // --- END click on list item ----

}
```

I just want to get the onClick to work, I don't care that it doesn't do anything at the moment. I'll put that functionality in later.

---

An example of `record_2.xml`:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/rMakeTV" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
    android:text="Make" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="16dp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" > 

</TextView>
```

I've tried this, based on what Sam is pointing out, but the list items are still not clickable.

```
        // --- Click on list item ---

    AdapterView<?> clickList = getListView();
    clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    // --- END click on list item ----
```

It seems to me that since there's no reference to the `records` ListAdapter in the `setOnItemClickListener` it won't work?

Comment: What are your items? can we see record_2 layout?

Comment: Do you use an `onClick`, `clickable`, `focusable`, etc attribute anywhere in `record_2.xml`? If you do then the row layout will absorb the touch event and your `OnItemClickListener` will never be called...

Comment: Sam, no I don't use any of those, they're pretty standard textviews. An example: `<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rMakeTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Make"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" >
                    </TextView>`

Comment: Interesting, what have you tried in the `onItemClick()` method? Have you tried something simple like `Log.v("Test", "A row was clicked with OnItemClick!");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything in your `onItemClick()` method, how will you know if it is working (unless you are using the debugger)? Since your code looks fine, try something simple like this:

```
ListView clickList = getListView();
clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.v("Test", "A row was clicked with OnItemClick!");
    }
});
```

Watch your logcat for these messages.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code works! I changed it from Log.v to a Toast so I could see if it was working on my phone - and it does! Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove `AdapterView` before `OnItemClickListener` in the method `setOnItemClickListener()`. Or replace `AdapterView` with simple `View`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it has no effect, the list items are still not clickable. I tried `ListView clickList = getListView();
  clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {` and `ListView clickList = getListView();
  clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {` neither one worked, no effect, still not clickable.

Comment: The [`OnItemClicklistener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is part of the `AdapterView` class, calling `View.OnItemClickListener` won't work. Also the main difference between calling just `new OnItemClickListener()` and `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` is limiting which files you import, they point to the same class.